# Upload via Media to old folder in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upload, media

I am trying to upload image from Media section in Wordpress Admin but it is taking old year folder 2015 instead of 2016. but when i upload same image from Post section then it comes to 2016 folder...

Can you please let me know how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I found that when i renamed this plugin called "wr-megamenu", it got resolved.. can anyone help how to resolve that plugin issue?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to `Dashboard -> Settings -> Media`
2. Enter the desired location in Store uploads in this folder
3. Uncheck organize my uploads into month - and year - based folders

---

This specify the global upload location. To specify a per-file upload location, you will need to use a Plugin, such as **[WP Easy Uploader](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-easy-uploader/)**

Try this...it will solve your issue.